# Developing iOS apps with local Express/NodeJS/Neo4J server stack?

Tags: ios, node.js, neo4j, development-environment

Is it possible to have an `Express/NodeJS/Neo4J` stack running on a dev laptop at home, say on `port 3000` and connect to it from an app in development running on an `iPhone/iPad?`

I am thinking that since the data exchange would happen via RESTful services as long as the app knows the IP address and the port number to connect to within the home network, things should just work. But since I have zero knowledge of iOS programming, maybe I am not aware of restrictions imposed to apps in dev mode running on devices BEFORE they are actually being offered on the appstore.

In other words, do I need to have a development server to run an `Express/NodeJS/Neo4J` stack for `iOS` development, or would it be fine to work within the home network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run your app's backend server from your development machine. I do this all the time. As you pointed out, you only need to know the IP address and port of the server. As long as the device and server are on the same network, you'll be fine. You can use both the simulator and a real device to access the server running on your dev machine.

Comment: Wonderful. I figured it should have been possible, but I wanted to hear from someone who had actually done it. Thanks for the quick reply!!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Server"
                                                                   message:@"Choose server to point to"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction *button1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Development" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                        //code to run once button is pressed
                                                    }];
    UIAlertAction *button2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Production" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //code to run once button is pressed
    }];
    [alert addAction:button1];
    [alert addAction:button2];
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alert popoverPresentationController];
    popPresenter.sourceView = self.view;
    //To present the actionsheet the bottom of screen
    popPresenter.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.createBtn.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, self.createBtn.frame.size.width, self.createBtn.frame.size.height stack-exchange-apk_202008 software apkarchive Stack Exchange APK installer Internet Archive HTML5 Uploader 1.6.4 Android Stack Exchange APK installer franck.Dernoncourt@gmail.com 2020-08-28 17:18:14 2020-08-28 17:18:14 [curator]validator@archive.org[/curator][date]20200828172231[/date][comment]checked for malware[/comment] phonesoftware
```